# Including a sign up form in the master layout

Tags: laravel

I would like to put my sign up form in my footer of my Laravel app so that it appears on all the pages on footer. I have no idea regarding this. Would appreciate basic sample codes for the controller and the form.
CONTACT FORM

```
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{old('email') }}">
                    <span class="errors">{{ $errors->first('email') }} </span>

                  @csrf
                  <span class="subscribe-button"><input type="submit" value="subscribe" /></span>
             </form>
        </div>
```

SubscribeController.php

```
      <?php

       namespace App\Http\Controllers;

       use App\Mail\SubscribeMail;
       use Illuminate\Http\Request;
       use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail

       class SubscribeController extends Controller
        {
         public function create()
          {
          return view('contact.subscribe');
          }


       public function store()
           {
          $data = request()->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

         Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new SubscribeMail($data));

         return redirect('');
       }
```

The subscribe.blade is inside my footer using  @include('contact.subscribe')

Comment: it should work the way you have it

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, keep up! However, you have some issues inside the store function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
           $data = $request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
           ]);

         Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new SubscribeMail($data));

         return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Anyway, if you are looking to include a sign-up form that appears on all of the pages you should define a layout that has a basic header, footer, and a sign-up form.

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <footer>
          <p>Amazing footer with the sign-up form</p>
          <form>
            <!-- Inputs -->
          </form>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

After that, you can create any number of pages, which should extend your main layout.

```
<!-- Stored in resources/pages/home.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Home Page')

@section('content')
    <p>This is my Home page.</p>
@endsection
```

Read more about it on official Laravel documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#defining-a-layout